# Androidでoverlay表示させたViewにタッチイベントを消費させないようにする

Tags: android, android-layout

Androidで常に最前面に表示させるようなOverlay表示をするために、ServiceのonStartCommandに次のような実装をしています。

```
// Viewからインフレータを作成する
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

// 重ね合わせするViewの設定を行う
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

// WindowManagerを取得する
mWm = (WindowManager) getSystemService( Context.WINDOW_SERVICE );

// レイアウトファイルから重ね合わせするViewを作成する
mView = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.service_overlay, null);

// Viewを画面上に重ね合わせする
mWm.addView(mView, params);
```

この時、`service_overlay.xml`に

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="stack overflow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

のように全画面を覆い尽くす`TextView`を配置すると、`TextView`の下にある`Button`にはタッチイベントは渡りますが、`Button`の範囲外をタッチしても通常のレイヤーにあるアプリにタッチイベントが渡りません。

`TextView`を削除して、`Button`の範囲外をタッチすれば、通常のレイヤーにあるアプリにタッチイベントは渡ります。
このことから、ルート要素である`RelativeLayout`自体はタッチイベントを消費していないと予想しています。
そうだとすると、`TextView`がタッチイベントを消費していることになるのですが、その下の`Button`にはイベントが渡っているので、`TextView`もタッチイベントを消費していないということになります。
ですが実際はタッチイベントは渡っていません。

オーバーレイ表示のViewがタッチイベントを消費せず、通常レイヤーのアプリにタッチイベントを渡すにはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: ルート要素のRelativeLayoutに色をつけてみて、TextViewあり/なしで領域に変化あるか確認してみましたか？

Comment: ルート要素に色を付けて、TextViewあり/なしや、他の要素を配置していろいろと試してみた結果、ルート要素がwrap_contentsのような形で変形しているのが確認できました。
ということは、ルート要素がイベントを消費しているわけではなく、`FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`のようなレイヤーを超えたタッチを可能にするフラグがあるときは、ルート要素のlayout_widthなどのプロパティを上書きして伸縮させているということですね。
なんらかのViewがあるところのタッチは下のレイヤーにまで伝播しないということですね・・。