# android - overlay表示しているViewでACTION_OUTSIDE後にACTION_MOVEを取得したい

Tags: android, android-layout

Androidでoverlay表示をしているViewで下の通常のレイヤーにタッチイベントを伝播させつつ、`ACTION_MOVE`などのイベントを補足したいのですが、現状`FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH`を利用することで、`ACTION_OUTSIDE`は捕捉できています。

[以前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14544/android%E3%81%A7overlay%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9Fview%E3%81%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%82%A4%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E6%B6%88%E8%B2%BB%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)からの試行錯誤中です。

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

mView = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.service_overlay, null);

mWm = (WindowManager) getSystemService( Context.WINDOW_SERVICE );
mWm.addView(mView, params);

mView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d( TAG, "onTouch; act: " + event.getAction());
        return true;
    }
});
```

servive_overlay.xmlは、次のように空の`RelatveLayout`のみです。

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#80FF8080">
</RelativeLayout>
```

`ACTION_OUTSIDE`を補足後、`ACTION_MOVE`を補足したいのですが、`RelativeLayout`をカスタムビューなどに変更して`onTouchEvent`や`onInterceptTouchEvent`、`dispatchTouchEvent`等を利用しても捕捉できません。
`onInterceptTouchEvent`では`ACTION_OUTSIDE`すら発生しませんでした。

`ACTION_MOVE`補足中は、下のレイヤーにタッチイベントを伝えられなくても良いです。

やりたいことは、適当に設定したホットスポットでタッチを開始し、そこからジェスチャーを補足するようなイメージです。
ホットスポットが矩形ではないため、Buttonや他のViewを用いた方法は使えません。
（overlayしているViewではsetRotationやsetXなども正しく動きませんでした）

なにか良い方法はありますか？